# Python & Pandas : TypeError: to_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flavor'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sql, json

I want to store JSON Data into MySQL Database using Python.
I used `dataframe` of `pandas`. I found that `to_sql()` can do this job easily.

**Python Code:**

```
jdata=json.loads(json_data)
df=pandas.DataFrame(jdata)
df.to_sql(con=con, name='crashTable', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

**Output:**

```
TypeError: to_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flavor'
```

I got this error message. How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the documentation [0.22](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) and [0.24.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), the flavor does not exist in the argument list of the `to_sql` method. You're probably running the `0.24.1` version which does not need `flavor` argument.